# Como criar diretório e fazer upload de arquivo

Tags: php, upload, mkdir

Bom estou com a seguinte dúvida, é possível criar um diretório com o mkdir e no mesmo código PHP inserir arquivos vindos de uploads nesse diretório criado?

Por exemplo estou com um formulário onde recebo arquivos por upload, e gostaria de criar uma pasta e jogar esses arquivos nela no mesmo momento, é possível fazer isso tudo no mesmo código de forma que utilize somente um action?

Código PHP:

```
$vregistro = utf8_decode($_POST['f_registro']); //Recebe valor de um input

mkdir("C:\test\Arquivos\Documentos/$vregistro", 0777, true); 
//Cria uma pasta com o nome designado na variável

$uploaddir = 'C:\test\Arquivos\Documentos/';       
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fanexo']['name']);              

echo                                                                 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fanexo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
```

Comment: sim é possível, poste seu código

Comment: Poste o código, por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível,

Nesse link tem um exemplo de upload de arquivo
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Para criar a pasta você utiliza o comando mkdir no link abaixo tem mais detalhes http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mkdir.php

você pode verificar se o diretório já existe antes de criar, e depois savar o arquivo

```
$uploaddir = dirname(__FILE__).'/nome_diretorio';     
if (!is_dir($uploaddir)) {
   mkdir($uploaddir);
}
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fanexo"]["tmp_name"], $uploaddir)) {
   echo "UPLOAD ok.";
} else {
   echo "Erro.";
}
```

Usando dirname(__FILE __) o caminho fica relativo ao diretório do arquivo atual.

Espero ter ajudado